# Unity Profiler - PlayerLoop almost 100% on Android devices

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, profiler

I'm checking `profiler performance` of my game on an Android device. When I check `CPU Usage` I noticed that `PlayerLoop` is at 99.6% and the biggest percentage is consumed in `Semaphore.WaitForSignal` with 32.5% and the second is `PlayerConnection.Poll` with 27%.

Can someone explain if there is a way to improve this? Is the `PlayerLoop` at 99.6% "normal" or is too high?

Below screenshot results from **Xiaomi MI 5 Android 8**
[image: Profiler status]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provided percent in the profiler is **"How mutch this item, contributes to the current execute time"** and not "How much CPU you are using.

What is interesting to you is time in milliseconds for the biggest items. And whether something is too much or too little depends on what framerate you want to achieve.

**What is Player Loop**

The Player loop is the total time your game took to render 1 frame. In there you can find, all your scripts, rendering, and other engine functions.

**What is Semaphore.WaitForSignal**

Your Graphics pipeline is waiting for something else to finish. Usually, it means rendering is taking a while to finish, and some other parts of the graphics pipeline can't proceed until rendering is complete.

**Is Player loop 99.6% normal**

Yes, it preferably should always be around 100% unless you are in the editor.

**What is exactly 27ms in the player loop**

Total time required to process and render one frame. To achieve 30fps in-game you need to have all frames below 33ms (1000ms/30fps)

You can find more information here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerCPU.html

Comment: So what is exactly the 27.24 ms in PlayerLoop? Still didn't get it if the 99.6% is way too high or not.

Comment: Please look at this edit. And to answer is 27ms to mutch? Yes and no. If this is 27ms on the latest the most powerful phone, then Yes. If this is on most budget phone on the market, you are good. You need to answer this yourself as we don't know how your game looks like, and what device you are running on. Please read the documentation from the link in the answer. @Johny

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The screenshot above is from a Xiaomi MI 5 Android 8, budget device (from 2016) so this can be considered good performance. I will test on more devices and see the results.